# CustomValidator client side validation for multiple dropdowns

Tags: javascript, asp.net, customvalidator

I have 4 customvalidator on page and 4 checkboxlist that I want to do validation.I want to validate at least one of checkbox is checked inside each checkboxlist. For validation function I use below. For All Customvalidator I have created attribute name 'cv' with values as 'cv_1','cv_2','cv_3','cv_4'. I have given class name to checkboxlist same as attribute name.

```
      function CustomValidate(sender, args)
      {

      var valid = false;

      var cv = sender.attributes["cv"];

      $('.' + cv + ':has(:checked)').each(function ()
           {

              valid = true;
           });

      args.IsValid = valid;
      }
```

Now my issue is that when I don't check any checkbox my validation function as expected. But For example, I have checked checkbox in one checkboxlist but not other three, I am expecting validation error. But it make all validation true. What is wrong with my javascript function?

Comment: In the beginning you're saying `I want to validate at least one of checkbox is checked.`  at the end you're saying `I have checked checkbox in one checkboxlist but not other three, I am expecting validation error`. You're question itself seems to be conflicting.. please make it clear..

Comment: Actually checkboxlist is container that has more than one checkbox for each checkboxlist.I have 4 checkboxlist. Now my requirement is that for all checkboxlist at least one checkbox must be checked . So If I don't check anything inside any checkboxlist validation works. But if I checked checkbox from one checkboxlist but not other three checkboxlist, It should give me validation error. But it is not giving me that.